# Double Populating Menu and Dropdown from XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to populate a Menu and it's dropdown options from an XML file.
I can populate the menu but the dropdown options do not show.

XML:

```
<dropdown>
    <topo category="Main Opt 1">
        <opcao value="1">Opcao 1</opcao>
        <opcao value="2">Opcao 2</opcao>
        <opcao value="3">Opcao 3</opcao>
        <opcao value="4">Opcao 4</opcao>
    </topo>
    <topo category="Main Opt 2">
    </topo>
</dropdown>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu" id="mySelect2">
  <li class="inicio"><a href"#">Inicio</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "dados_menu.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
var select = $('#mySelect2');
var select1 = $('#mySelect');
var optionsHtml = new Array();
var optionsHtml1 = new Array();
$('topo', xml).each(function(){
    var label = $(this).attr('category');
    optionsHtml.push("<li class='dropdown'> <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>"+label+"<b class='carret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu' id='mySelect'></ul></li>");
    $('opcao', xml).each(function(){
        var label1 = $(this).text();
        optionsHtml1.push( "<li><a href='#' class='ddindent'>"+label1+"</a></li>");
    });
    optionsHtml1 = optionsHtml1.join('');
    select1.append(optionsHtml1);
});
optionsHtml = optionsHtml.join('');
select.append(optionsHtml);
} //sucess close
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you use `$('opcao', xml)` where you should have used `$('opaco', this)`.

I'd suggest a more structured approach:

```js
function buildMenuFromXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('topo').each(function () {
        var category = $(this).attr('category'),
            $menuItem = $("<li class='dropdown'></li>"),
            $submenu = $("<ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul>");

        $(this).find('opcao').each(function () {
            $submenu.append("<li><a href='#' class='ddindent'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>");
        });

        $menuItem.append("<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>" + category + "<b class='carret'></b></a>");
        $menuItem.append($submenu);
        $menuItem.appendTo('#mySelect');
    });
}
```

usage:

```
$.get("dados_menu.xml").done(buildMenuFromXml);
```

Open and run the code snippet below to to see it in action.

```js
function buildMenuFromXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('topo').each(function () {
        var category = $(this).attr('category'),
            $menuItem = $("<li class='dropdown'></li>"),
            $submenu = $("<ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul>");

        $(this).find('opcao').each(function () {
            $submenu.append("<li><a href='#' class='ddindent'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>");
        });

        $menuItem.append("<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>" + category + "<b class='carret'></b></a>");
        $menuItem.append($submenu);
        $menuItem.appendTo('#mySelect');
    });
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------

buildMenuFromXml('<dropdown>\
    <topo category="Main Opt 1">\
        <opcao value="1">Opcao 1</opcao>\
        <opcao value="2">Opcao 2</opcao>\
        <opcao value="3">Opcao 3</opcao>\
        <opcao value="4">Opcao 4</opcao>\
    </topo>\
    <topo category="Main Opt 2">\
    </topo>\
</dropdown>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu" id="mySelect"></ul>
```

Notes:

- I recommend against using `$(selector, context)`. Use the way more straight-forward `$(context).find(selector)` instead.
- Use `$.get()` for simple GET requests.
- Try to use sensible variable names. For example, an `<ul>` called `select` is misleading. `select` and `select1` are confusing.
- For more complex HTML building tasks, don't use jQuery but let a dedicated HTML templating library do it.

Comment: Implemented the 3 best practices recommended. 

I understand now why I should used a HTML templating library.

Thank you for your time and for the notes.